# How to toggle layer visibility in QGIS using Python?

Tags: python, qgis

How can I toggle layer visibility in QGIS via Python API?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is from the QGIS docs, if you are running QGIS => 1.5

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from qgis import core, gui
i = qgis.utils.iface
# load a georeferenced raster layer
loadedLayer = i.addRasterLayer('c:\\data\\a_map.png')
# get legend
legend = i.legendInterface()
# check current visibility
legend.isLayerVisible(loadedLayer)
# set visibility off 
legend.setLayerVisible(loadedLayer, False)
# and on again!
legend.setLayerVisible(loadedLayer, True)
```

I guess you would just swap out `loadedLayer = i.addRasterLayer('c:\\data\\a_map.png')` with the layer that you want to hide, which you could get using something like:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer(QString theLayerId)
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is not available for QGIS3. In QGIS3, I use the code below:

```
QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(lyr.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(False)
```

Also, we can toggle on and off all the layers by:

```
visible = True # or False
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
allLayers = root.layerOrder()
for layer in allLayers:
    root.findLayer(layer.id()).setItemVisibilityChecked(visible)
```

Comment: Your first code block isn't a toggle, but explicitly sets the target layer invisible.

Comment: @Legato, use `setItemVisibilityChecked(boolean)` to toggle the layer